# PHP Integration test using Behat

Tags: php, testing, integration-testing, behat

I am new to Integration test, I have a task to create integration test scenarios, for cli:  `bin/console import:products products.xml` which responsible for reading the data from xml file and insert the data to databases tables.

```
final class ProductImporter extends AbstractImporter implements ProductImporterInterface
{
private ResourceResolverInterface $productResourceResolver;

private ProductRelationsPurifierInterface $productRelationsPurifier;

private ProductImagesAssignerInterface $productImagesAssigner;

private ProductChannelsAssignerInterface $productChannelsAssigner;

private ProductDesignerAssignerInterface $productDesignerAssigner;

private static array $channels = [];

private static array $designers = [];

public function __construct(
    ResourceResolverInterface $productResourceResolver,
    ProductRelationsPurifierInterface $productRelationsPurifier,
    ProductImagesAssignerInterface $productImagesAssigner,
    ProductChannelsAssignerInterface $productChannelsAssigner,
    ProductDesignerAssignerInterface $productDesignerAssigner
) {
    $this->productResourceResolver = $productResourceResolver;
    $this->productRelationsPurifier = $productRelationsPurifier;
    $this->productImagesAssigner = $productImagesAssigner;
    $this->productChannelsAssigner = $productChannelsAssigner;
    $this->productDesignerAssigner = $productDesignerAssigner;
}

public function import(array $row): ?ResourceInterface
{
    $code = $this->getColumnValue(self::CODE_TAG, $row);
    $designerId = (int) $this->getColumnValue('designerID', $row);
    $attributes = $this->getColumnValue(self::ATTRIBUTES_TAG, $row);
    $productChannels = $this->getColumnValue('channelAttributes', $row)['channel'];
    $images = $this->getColumnValue(self::IMAGES_TAG, $row)['image'];
    $isHidden = (bool) $attributes['isHidden'];

    /** @var ProductInterface $product */
    $product = $this->productResourceResolver->resolveResource($code);

    if (null !== $product->getId()) {
        // only if product is already in db
        $this->productRelationsPurifier->purifyRelations($product);
    }

    $product->setCode($code);
    $product->setEnabled(!$isHidden);
    $this->productImagesAssigner->assignImages($product, $images);
    $this->productDesignerAssigner->assign($product, $designerId);
    $this->productChannelsAssigner->assign($product, $productChannels);

    return $product;
}

public function getResourceCode(): string
{
    return 'product';
}

public static function setChannels(array $channels): void
{
    self::$channels = $channels;
}

public static function getChannels(): array
{
    return self::$channels;
}

public static function addDesigner(DesignerInterface $designer): void
{
    self::$channels[] = $designer;
}

public static function getDesigners(int $designerId): ?DesignerInterface
{
    /** @var DesignerInterface $designer */
    foreach (self::$designers as $designer) {
        if ($designer->getId() === $designerId) {
            return $designer;
        }
    }

    return null;
 }
}
```

My question is not to write me the test, but to show me how/where can i start writing the integration test, also the steps i need to do.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

First you'll need to setup behat if you have not done that yet. This means roughly:

- Require it through composer
- Add a configuration
- Add a first context
- Write a .feature file

The feature file is written in human readable language while the context translates that into code. Once you've got your setup complete you can write the feature file line by line and implement the code behind it using the context file.

Here's an [example](https://github.com/matthiasnoback/symfony-console-form/blob/master/features/interactive.feature) feature file and here is an [example](https://github.com/matthiasnoback/symfony-console-form/blob/master/features/bootstrap/FeatureContext.php) context for it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have read the Quick Start guide on Behat.
Important things you might've missed:

1. Require with `composer require --dev`
2. Run `vendor/bin/behat --init` which will generate skeleton files

If your Integration tests are about running some kind of web browser and clicking through buttons — you'll also want to install [Mink Extension](https://github.com/Behat/MinkExtension) to have ready-made implemented low-level sentences for page navigation.

If you want to have access to your actual application during the test (e.g. create some ORM objects in DB during the test set up or getting pre-authenticated session or something) you'll want to instantiate your actual application in your context (see `index.php` or `bootstrap.php` files of your project to find out how it's instantiated). In this case you probably better use separate context for that purpose, so that you could use it as subcontext of other test contexts.